# Add 3 spaces in a squence

Tags: javascript

I've got a 8 digits string. How can I add a space in the following sequesnce

```
var str = "11111111";
//expected output 1111 11 11
```

Add a space after first 4 digits and then the next two digits and then before the last two digits.

I know to do a single space ( `.replace(/[_]/g," ");`). But how do I do 3 in the above sequence?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use a regular expression replace

```
"11111111".replace(/(....)(..)(..)/, '$1 $2 $3')
```

Comment: Or as an alternative `"11111111".replace(/(.{4})(.{2})(.{2})/, '$1 $2 $3')`. @potatopeelings' version is probably more readable though.

Comment: Can you please explain briefly where are you defining the space here? What if I need to add a `.` instead of a space?

Comment: The space is in the 2nd parameter to the replace ($1<space>$2<space>$3). You can do `"11111111".replace(/(....)(..)(..)/, '$1.$2.$3')`

Answer (score 2):

You can use substring method:

```
var result = str.substring(0, 4) + " " + str.substring(4, 6) + " " + str.substring(6)
```